# jenkinsfile - maven clean build failed with syntax error. how to use multisteps in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, declarative

Started by user admin
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 13: Expected a step @ line 13, column 9.
def mavenHome = tool name:"Maven-3.8.6", type: "maven"
^

WorkflowScript: 14: Expected a step @ line 14, column 9.
def mavenCMD = "${mavenHome}/bin/mvn"
^

2 errors

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1107)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:677)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:689)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:513)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
```

[withMaven] downstreamPipelineTriggerRunListener - Failure to introspect build steps: java.io.IOException: ProjectRL1 #16 did not yet start
[withMaven] downstreamPipelineTriggerRunListener - Failure to introspect build steps: java.io.IOException: ProjectRL1 #16 did not yet start
Finished: FAILURE

--------------------code--------------
pipeline {
agent any

stages {

```
stage("git clone"){
  steps {
    git 'https://github.com/sunilbennur/spring-boot-mongo-docker.git'
  }
}
stage("Maven clean build") {
  steps { 
    def mavenHome = tool name:"Maven-3.8.6", type: "maven"
    def mavenCMD = "${mavenHome}/bin/mvn"
    sh "${mavenCMD} clean package"
   }
}
```

}
}

Comment: were you able to find out the solution for this, I'm also facing same issue now. Please help:)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove pipeline and steps tag in the script and run the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).